# Python auth returns 401

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication

I have a python script that downloads a snapshot from a camera. I use auth to login to the camera. For older style cameras it works with no issues, with the new one it doesn't. I have tested the link and credentials by copying them from my python script to make sure they work and they do, but i still can't login and I am not sure why. The commented url is the one that works. The uniview one doesn't. I have replaced the password with the correct one and i also tested the link in Chromium and it works.

```
import requests

#hikvision old cameras
#url = 'http://192.168.100.110/ISAPI/Streaming/channels/101/picture'

#uniview
url = 'http://192.168.100.108:85/images/snapshot.jpg'

r = requests.get(url, auth=('admin','password'))

if r.status_code == 200:
    with open('/home/pi/Desktop/image.jpg', 'wb') as out:
        for bits in r.iter_content():
            out.write(bits)
else:
    print(r.status_code)
    print(r.content)
```

Below is the response I get

```
b'{\r\n"Response": {\r\n\t"ResponseURL": "/images/snapshot.jpg",\r\n\t"ResponseCode": 3,\r\n \t"SubResponseCode": 0,\r\n \t"ResponseString": "Not Authorized",\r\n\t"StatusCode": 401,\r\n\t"StatusString": "Unauthorized",\r\n\t"Data": "null"\r\n}\r\n}\r\n'
```

Comment: Can you please add the response headers

Comment: {'Content-Length': '222', 'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 'Connection': 'close', 'WWW-Authenticate': 'Digest realm="e4f14c21fce9", nonce="40979f50366f57ba45ebdc753f76e9", stale="false", algorithm="MD5", qop="auth"', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN'}  I modified the nonce for security. Not sure if it matters for diagnostics.

Answer (score 2):

So it looks like `hikvisio` are using [Basic_access_authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) while `uniview` are using [Digest_access_authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) so according to the [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/authentication/) you need to change your request to:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('admin','password'))
```

Comment: I tried that, but it tells me HTTPDigestAuth is not defined. I am using the Thonny python editor 3.2.6. It reports using Python 3.7.3

Comment: Maybe you didn't import it , or using an old `requests` version